# 48-bit bitwise operations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, random, bitwise-operators

I've been given the task of porting Java's `Java.util.Random()` to JavaScript, and I've run across a huge performance hit/inaccuracy using bitwise operators in Javascript on sufficiently large numbers. Some cursory research states that "bitwise operators in JavaScript are inherently slow," because internally it appears that JavaScript will cast all of its double values into signed 32-bit integers to do the bitwise operations ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for more on this.) Because of this, I can't do a direct port of the Java random number generator, and I need to get the same numeric results as `Java.util.Random()`. Writing something like

```
  this.next = function(bits) {
    if (!bits) {
       bits = 48;
    }
    this.seed = (this.seed * 25214903917 + 11) & ((1 << 48) - 1);
    return this.seed >>> (48 - bits);
  };
```

(which is an almost-direct port of the `Java.util.Random()`) code won't work properly, since Javascript can't do bitwise operations on an integer that size.)

I've figured out that I can just make a seedable random number generator in 32-bit space using the Lehmer algorithm, but the trick is that I need to get the same values as I would with `Java.util.Random()`. What should I do to make a faster, functional port?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `foo & ((1 << 48) - 1)` you should be able to use `foo % Math.pow(2,48)`.

All numbers in Javascript are 64-bit floating point numbers, which is sufficient to represent any 48-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

48-bit bitwise operations are not possible in JavaScript. You could use two numbers to simulate it though.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a boolean array of 48 booleans, and implement the shifting yourself. I don't know if this is faster, though; but I doubt it, since all booleans are stored as doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that a bit shift is directly equivalent to a multiplication or division by a power of 2.

```
1 << x == 1 * Math.pow(2,x)
```

It is slower than bit shifting, but allows you to extend beyond 32 bits. It **may** be a faster solution for `bits > 32`, once you factor in the additional code you need to support higher bit counts, but you'll have to do some profiling to find out.